# how to using dynamic route on @Url.Action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i try to create dynamic link on asp.net mvc view, with value from database. 
this my code

```
@foreach (var menu in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <h4><span class="@menu.Glyphicon"></span> @menu.CategoryName</h4>
            <ul>
                @foreach (var mn in menu.LeftMenus)
                {
                    if (mn.RouteValue == null)
                    {
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action(@mn.ActionName, @mn.ControllerName)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span> @mn.MenuName</a></li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action(@mn.ActionName, @mn.ControllerName, new { @mn.RouteValue })"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span> @mn.MenuName</a></li>
                    }
                }
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
```

when i parse @RouteValue to @url.Action, route value was wrong and be like

```
<a href="/Import?RouteValue=workType%20%3D%201">
```

this my model

```
public class LeftMenuViewModel
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Glyphicon { get; set; }
    public List<LeftMenu> LeftMenus { get; set; }
}

public class LeftMenu
{
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public object RouteValue { get; set; }
}
```

how can i use dynamic route value?

Comment: what is your expected routevalue?

Comment: you can use `@Html.Encode(mn.RouteValue)`

Comment: my goal s create url.action like this <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Import", new { workType = 1 })">

Comment: try `<a href="@Url.Action(mn.ActionName, mn.ControllerName, new {  workType = Html.Encode(mn.RouteValue) })"></a>`

Comment: the problem is, i get work type from database, so the value from database like workType = 1

Comment: means `mn.RouteValue` is `1`?

Comment: no no, mn.RouteValue is workType = 1

Comment: i get parameter name and parameter value from  database

Comment: try `<a href="@Url.Action(mn.ActionName, mn.ControllerName, new { Html.Encode(mn.RouteValue) })"></a>`

Comment: still error when i try your code. "Invalid anonymous type member declarator "

Comment: You need to pass an object (not a value type) to the routeValues parameter. Can you show your model.

Comment: instead of using `@Url.Action()` you can try `<a href="@mn.ControllerName/@mn.ActionName?@mn.RouteValue">....</a>`

Comment: or if you want to remove unwanted spaces `%20` then try `<a href="@mn.ControllerName/@mn.ActionName?@mn.RouteValue.Replace(" ","")">....</a>`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke  thats my model

Comment: @Kartikeya thats work if my parameter value is string or int, but many parameter value using object like @Url.Action("MappingList", "Mapping", new { mappingType = NewMiddleware.Repository.ViewModel.MappingType.City })

Comment: @noviankristianto, If you initialize `model.RouteValue = new object { ID = "someValue" };`, then use `@Html.ActionLink(@mn.MenuName, @mn.ActionName, @mn.ControllerName, @mn.RouteValue, null)` (and no need for the `if` block)

Answer (score 2):

I 've found the appropriate answer for my problem.

This my model

```
public class LeftMenuViewModel
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Glyphicon { get; set; }
    public List<LeftMenu> LeftMenus { get; set; }
}

public class LeftMenu
{
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public object RouteValue { get; set; }
}
```

... after this, in my view, I write this:

```
RouteValueDictionary routeValue = new RouteValueDictionary();
                        routeValue.Add(@mn.ParameterName,@mn.RouteValue);
<li><a href="@Url.Action(@mn.ActionName, @mn.ControllerName, routeValue)"<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span> @mn.MenuName</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set parameter name with Route value like

```
new { @m.ParameterName = @mn.routeValue }
```